# redirecting a mobirise email form

Tags: javascript, forms, mobirise

I'm creating a new website for my company using mobirise.  The mobirise templates come with predesigned email forms that were created using formoid.  When a user uses the email form to send an email the information is sent to formoid and then formoid sends the information to me at my email address.  All of the coding in the email form is behind the scenes, so I can't actually see what it's doing.

On one of my forms I need to have the page redirect to another page where users will be able to upload a file to my server using another script.  I have contacted mobirise to ask them if they could tell me how to redirect after the user clicks the submit button, but they said I had to contact formoid.  So far I haven't gotten a response back from formoid so I thought I would try to look for a solution on my own.

I have tried adding javascript code to the coding on the page, but as I said, most of the coding of the form is somewhere behind the scenes and I can't figure out exactly which coding is performing the form's submit action.

What I was hoping for is a suggestion about how I could add some additional JavaScript coding that would watch for the submit button in the form being clicked and then redirect the page.  I'm not positive this is even possible, but I figured that if anyone would be helpful it would be the people who post solutions here.  I'm rather new to JavaScript, so I'm not sure where to start and I don't want to experiment for hours and hours and get frustrated because nothing is working.

So, if anyone can give me an idea here I would greatly appreciate it.  Below is the coding for the form in case it helps:

```
                <div data-form-alert="true">
                    <div hidden="" data-form-alert-success="true" class="alert alert-form alert-success text-xs-center">Thanks for uploading your audio file!</div>
                </div>


                <form action="https://mobirise.com/" method="post" data-form-title="FTP Upload">

                    <input type="hidden" value="NTcF3QgiRzQHgm5xv+UnYlBBGPR27Q6NZwj5EPuecwUNxuL8vndMlaaoM2PpzlkXlNaFBrtr2mU+CfZxfef01mKMpaQkezUMhyWXZgieem0/pt/V/nU0iUetLNqsEpj7" data-form-email="true">

                    <div class="row row-sm-offset">

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label" for="form1-3o-name">Name<span class="form-asterisk">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="" data-form-field="Name" id="form1-3o-name">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label" for="form1-3o-email">Email<span class="form-asterisk">*</span></label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required="" data-form-field="Email" id="form1-3o-email">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label" for="form1-3o-phone">Phone</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" data-form-field="Phone" id="form1-3o-phone">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="form1-3o-message">One or more files are being uploaded to the WORDsmart server.  </label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="7" data-form-field="Message" id="form1-3o-message"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">CONTACT US</button></div>

                </form>
```

Comment: I suggest you make your question smaller in order to get helps

Answer (score 1):

in this case, I would recommend you to use another form. As far as I know form wouldn't work if you would bring any changes to form of Mobirise. Just use another form creator and implement it manually to Mobirise's project after publication to the local folder (the project of Mobirise).

You can read tutorial about publishing here: https://mobirise.com/help/local-host-369.html

Answer (score 0):

Just change the action field in the first line of the form, to the page were you would like to send the data.

The next hidden input line with the public key may be deleted also.